# CSS not loading in Codeigniter

Tags: css, codeigniter

The problem is that css file is not loading in codeigniter 3.0.

But when I use firebug, the correct link is which I found.

Works fine with pagination which I aim for.

Only not working css file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bbs/include/css/bootstrap.css" />
```

**If I were wrong, firebug wouldn't read bootstrap.css, isn't it?**

But through firebug, I can check my bootstrap.css file source.

I tried many answers in Stackoverflow.

I tried
.htaccess issue (which is

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|include|captcha|robots\.txt)
```

because my css file is in include folder. And include folder has same 
location with application folder.

F5 crash. (which is probarbly caching problem experts say.)
but not working.

oh, using base_url is carrying the same result. Just not loaded.

What should I do?
I spent several times and am exhausted.

Sorry for repeated question.

Comment: You need to use <?php echo base_url();?> in src also make sure your url helper autoloaded. And make sure css in assets folder in main directory.

Comment: Thank you, wolfgang! It makes my brain better ! your tip helped me to solve the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this `<?php echo base_url(); ?>`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>bbs/include/css/bootstrap.css" />
```

in `config/config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Your `.htaccess` will be

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

So your folder structurer would be like this

```
 1. application
 2. bbs
     - include
         1. css
           - bootstrap.css
 3. index.php
 4. .htaccess
 5. system
```